# How to display a dropdown for ForeignKey models on the PARENT admin page

Tags: python, django, model, admin

Can't seem to figure this out. I have a model - Show, and Episode, which has a ForiegnKey relationship to Show. On the Show admin page, I want a dropdown display of all the Episodes, which will link to their admin model page... The only thing I can get is a collapsed form as a read only. I like the links to the admin page with this, but I just want it in a dropdown.

```
***models.py***
class Show(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), null=True, max_length=5000)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("slug"),  max_length=5000, unique=True)

class Episode(models.Model):
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show, verbose_name=_("show"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), null=True, max_length=5000)
```

```
***admin.py***
class ShowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'get_latest_duration', 'get_latest_pub_date',)
    inlines = [
        EpisodeInline,
    ]

class EpisodeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Episode
    fieldsets = (
        ('Episodes', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('title',),
        }),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the readonly fields. Here is an example:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ShowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('episode_list',)

    def episode_list(self, instance):
        # you may render a html list here with episode names
        return ",".join([x.name for x in instance.episodes]) # replace episodes with your model's related name
```

See example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields